# the API is returning an old value, is it possible to improve this process?

Tags: node.js, regex, reactjs, axios

I have an axios call to my mongoose/express server buy when I update some information from the reactjs webclient the useEffect code makes the call again so I can update my components states everywhere but is still retrieving old data. is it possible to improve this process, so I can get the right information?
A GraphQL implementation seems to be way faster though because is returning the right info. but I haven't achieved to do pagination with graphQL so I'm covering that part with a regular Axios for the moment.

Server side:

```
function paginatedItemsResults(model) {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page);
    const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit);

    const startIndex = (page - 1) * limit;
    const endIndex = page * limit;

    const results = {};

    if (endIndex < (await model.countDocuments())) {
      results.next = {
        page: page + 1,
        limite: limit,
      };
    }

    if (startIndex > 0) {
      results.previous = {
        page: page - 1,
        limite: limit,
      };
    }
    results.total = await model.countDocuments().exec();

    try {
      results.results = await model
        .find()
        .sort([["date", -1]])
        .limit(limit)
        .skip(startIndex)
        .exec();
      res.paginatedItemsResults = results;
      next();
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: e.message });
    }
  };
}

app.get("/itemspagination", paginatedItemsResults(Items), (req, res) => {
  res.json(res.paginatedItemsResults);
});
```

Client side:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let isSubscribed = true;
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          "https://**********/itemspagination?page=" +
            currentPage +
            "&limit=" +
            limitOfItemsByPage
        );
        if (isSubscribed) {
          dispatchPagination(
            buildItemPaginationAction({
              id: "next",
              value: res.data.next
                ? res.data.next.page
                : res.data.previous.page + 1,
            })
          );
          dispatchPagination(
            buildItemPaginationAction({
              id: "previous",
              value: res.data.previous ? res.data.previous.page : 1,
            })
          );
          dispatch(
            buildItemPaginationAction({
              id: "next",
              value: res.data.next
                ? res.data.next.page
                : res.data.previous.page + 1,
            })
          );
          dispatch(
            buildItemPaginationAction({
              id: "previous",
              value: res.data.previous ? res.data.previous.page : 1,
            })
          );
          setActualItems(res.data.results);
          setTotalProducts(res.data.total);
          setLoading(false);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    fetchProducts();
    return () => (isSubscribed = false);
  }, [currentPage, dispatch, limitOfItemsByPage, newItem, updateItem]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be due to caching. 
Try adding a new GET parameter to your URL like this:

```
const res = await axios.get(
      "https://**********/itemspagination?page=" +
        currentPage +
        "&limit=" +
        limitOfItemsByPage + "&nocache=" + (new Date).getTime()
    );
```

Comment: didn't work, but is axios the problem, if  do the fetch twice, shows the correct info. 
        let res = await axios.get(
          "http://localhost:4000/itemspagination?page=" +
            currentPage +
            "&limit=" +
            limitOfItemsByPage
        );
        res = await axios.get(
          "http://localhost:4000/itemspagination?page=" +
            currentPage +
            "&limit=" +
            limitOfItemsByPage
        );

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?